# getopt flexibility to make spaces work as well

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int o;
    int w = 10;

    while ((o = getopt(argc, argv, "w::")) != -1) {
        switch (o) {
            case 'w' :
                if (optarg) {
                    w = atoi(optarg);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n", w);
}
```

I want this to work

```
$ gcc -Wall theup.c
$ ./a.out -w 17
17
```

Currently does this

```
$ gcc -Wall theup.c
$ ./a.out -w 17
10
```

Is there any way to do this with getopt? It works for most of them like -w17 -w , but the space one doesn't work

Comment: Since a double colon indicates an option with an optional argument, it’s not going to work. `::` isn’t really good design in the first place, though. How about having two separate options – one that takes an argument and one that doesn’t?

Comment: Tried that. '-w' would crash. Unless you meant something else? I thought "w:w" or "w:w:" both crash.

Comment: They would be different letters.

Comment: It's curious how similar this is to the code provided in the Q&A (especially the answer) to [`getopt()` — how to set a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021769/getopt-how-to-set-a-default-value) but the posters are different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OP probably copied the answer code, and now is trying to take it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `::` (allows not to pass a value after the option), and a space, there would be an ambiguity between `-w 17` where `17` would be the value of the option and `-w 17` where `17` is another argument, which explains that getopt requires that the value is collated when using `::`

Even worse, think of the general case where there are other options. What would `-w -x` do ? `getopt` cannot predict that you're requiring a number after your option.

I would just change the getopt line to:

```
while ((o = getopt(argc, argv, "w:")) != -1) {
```

now omitting `-w` still gives `10` as the value is defaulted beforehand.